# Запускается Windows вместо USB

Tags: linux, bios, lubuntu

Скачал Lubuntu.iso, с помощью UltraISO сохранил на флеш-накопитель. В Advanced BIOS features поставил USB-HDD как First Boot Device. В Hard Disk Boot Priority поставил первым USB-HDD. После нажатия F10 запускается Windows. В чём ошибка?

Выбор USB-HDD в Boot Menu даёт тот же результат.

Comment: Скорее всего UltraISO не смогло нормально сделать флешку загрузочнойю Попробуйте записать образ через Rufus: https://rufus.ie/

Comment: Пишите руфусом  в dd режиме и все будет гуд. Можно еще контрольные суммы сверить

Comment: В обычном режиме система зависает после вклюсения, удаётся открыть только безопасный без сетевых драйверов

Comment: Попробуй через imageUSB записать

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вставьте по очереди во все порты.
Если вы правильно все выбрали, то биос либо не видит флешку, либо не считает ее загрузочной. Убедитесь, что записали правильно(видео хватает в ютубе).
Попробуйте на другом компьютере. Возможно плохо записался дистрибутив. 
Если такая же ситуация, то нужно перезаписать(а возможно и скачать другой образ).
Если на другом компьютере запускается установка, нужны фото настроек биоса. Возможно нужно добавить новое устройство.

Comment: Очень странный ответ.. Вы не учли UEFI или legacy. Ни слова про то, в каком формате находится съемный носитель и ни слова о методе записи (dd или другие каблуки)

Comment: при не соответствии UEFI или Legacy установка у меня начиналась и доходила до выбора диска. А тут вообще не начинается. А насчет формата съемного носителя, ultraISO предлагает само форматировать флешку